# Jenkins "build error" for the same build command which builds "success build" simultaneously

Tags: jenkins, build, version-control, triggers

I am using Jenkins for CI/CD on the AWS server. I have configured the job which includes Github private repo.

**"Build Trigger->Poll SCM-> * * * * *"** configuration is using for Build Triggering.

**"Build Environment->Delete workspace before build starts"** for the Build environment

**"Build-> Execute Shell"** (*the script is below*)

```
pm2 stop <*pm2 id*> 
npm install
npm run build 
pm2 serve build <*server port*>
```

The thing is this configuration built successfully and I could see the output as expected.
And the problem is the same configuration build failed for very next of success build. 
If I wait a few minutes and build the job again it "build success"

***So my query is, should I have to wait a certain time duration after a successful build or something else?***

Comment: Welcom to S.O!  I don't understand this part: "the same configuration build failed for very next of success build". I understand that you have a jenkins job which build well the first time and but in the next executions, fails. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, and after waiting a few minutes if I tried again it will build success again.

Comment: Do you wait to the next builds to a success execution or do you need to build manually?